# Is this a safe way to keep people out of my admin panel?

Tags: php

Newbie here,

Is this enough / safe to keep people out of my admin panel?

```
<?php if (isset($_SESSION["AccountLevelStandard"])) {
     echo "<script>location.href='home.php'</script>";
}
```

Comment: What if I disable Javascript…?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not even remotely. All someone has to do is disable JavaScript and they have full access to the page.

Use an HTTP redirect and exit the PHP script after sending it.

```
header("Location: home.php");
exit();
```

---

You shouldn't redirect people with standard level access, since that won't catch people who aren't logged in at all and so don't have *any* kind of access.

Test for people who are **not** admins instead.

Comment: I'm unable to edit headers due to an already active session. I saw someone said to not close their php tags to avoid this, is that feasible?

Also thanks for the exit tip.

Comment: @Pon — It depends on why the headers were already sent. You might need to restructure your code. [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php).